# start end date each month in the pas 12 months

Tags: python

This is my current code

```
class TimeSeries():
    def year(year):
        today = datetime.now()
        start_date = today+relativedelta(years=-1)
        mint, maxt = datetime.min.time(), datetime.max.time()
        for st in rrule(MONTHLY, count=24, bymonthday=(1,-1,), dtstart=start_date):
            yield st.combine(st, mint)
```

And this is output from this:

```
for y in TimeSeries().year():
    print(y)

2013-01-31 00:00:00
2013-02-01 00:00:00
2013-02-28 00:00:00
2013-03-01 00:00:00
2013-03-31 00:00:00
2013-04-01 00:00:00
2013-04-30 00:00:00
2013-05-01 00:00:00
2013-05-31 00:00:00
2013-06-01 00:00:00
2013-06-30 00:00:00
2013-07-01 00:00:00
2013-07-31 00:00:00
2013-08-01 00:00:00
2013-08-31 00:00:00
2013-09-01 00:00:00
2013-09-30 00:00:00
2013-10-01 00:00:00
2013-10-31 00:00:00
2013-11-01 00:00:00
2013-11-30 00:00:00
2013-12-01 00:00:00
2013-12-31 00:00:00
2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

The question is how I can force that counting are started from 2013-01-01 00:00:00 and month end like 2013-01-31 23:59:59 and so on.
And the end of loop ends on 2014-01-31 23:59:59 instead 2014-01-01 00:00:00

Also I like make start date and end date on one line:

```
2013-03-01 00:00:00 2013-03-31 23:59:59
2013-04-01 00:00:00 2013-03-30 23:59:59
...
...
2014-01-01 00:00:00 2014-01-31 23:59:59
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You have two completely separate problems here: putting the pairs on one line, and ending at 23:59:59. You should ask them as separate questions.

Comment: To print pairs on a line, the obvious thing to do is to change `TimeSeries` to `yield` pairs (as a tuple of start, stop values). It's pretty easy to pair them up in the `print` instead, but then there's no easy way to detect when you're straddling a month with the start or end (like your first value, `2013-01-31`, which has no `2013-01-01` to pair up with).

Answer (score 0):

First, are you really sure that you want `2013-03-31 23:59:59`. Date intervals are traditionally specified as half-open intervals—just like ranges in Python. And the reason for this is that `23:59:59` is not actually the end of a day.

Most obviously, `23:59:59.001` is later than that but on the same day. Python `datetime` objects include microseconds, so this isn't just a "meh, whatever" problem—if you, e.g., call `now()`, you can get a time that's incorrectly later than your "end of the day" on the same day.

Less obviously, on a day with a [leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), `23:59:60` is also later but on the same day.

---

But if you *really* want this, there are two obvious ways to get it:

---

You're already iterating dates instead of datetimes and combining the times in manually. And it's obvious when you're dealing with a day 1 vs. day -1, because the date's `day` member will be `1` or it won't be. So:

```
class TimeSeries():
    def year(year):
        today = datetime.now()
        start_date = today+relativedelta(years=-1)
        mint, maxt = datetime.min.time(), datetime.max.time()
        for st in rrule(MONTHLY, count=24, bymonthday=(1, -1,), dtstart=start_date):
            yield st.combine(st, mint if st.day=1 else maxt)
```

---

Alternatively, instead of iterating both first and last days, just iterate first days, and subtract a second to get the last second of the previous month:

```
class TimeSeries():
    def year(year):
        today = datetime.now()
        start_date = today+relativedelta(years=-1)
        mint, maxt = datetime.min.time(), datetime.max.time()
        for st in rrule(MONTHLY, count=24, bymonthday=(1,), dtstart=start_date):                
            dt = st.combine(st, mint)
            yield dt - timedelta(seconds=1)
            yield dt
```

---

As far as printing these in pairs… well, as written, that's an underspecified problem. The first value in your list is the second value in a pair—except when you run this on the 1st of a month. And likewise, the last date is the first value in a pair, except when you run this on the 31st. So, what do you want to do with them?

If this isn't obvious, look at your example. Your first value is `2013-01-31 00:00:00`, but your first pair doesn't start with 2013-01-31.

There are many things you *could* want here:

- Start with the first of the month a year ago, rather than the first first-or-last of the month that happened within the last year. And likewise for the end. So you would have `2013-01-01` in your list, and there would always be pairs.
- Start with the first month that started within the last year, and likewise for the end. So you wouldn't get `2013-01-31` in your list, and there would always be pairs.
- Use your current rule, and there's not a pair, use `None` for the missing value.
- etc.

Whatever rule you actually want can be coded up pretty easily. And then you'll probably want to `yield` in (start, end) tuples, so the `print` loop can just do this:

```
for start, end in TimeSeries().year():
    print(start, end)
```